# how to access other android sqlite database in other device using Lan cable (Lan Network) in android

Tags: android

[image]

There are two A and B android device connect Lan all use same sqLite database i parform insert update delete and view,if i Can Insert Record in A device then B Device View this record

Comment: You have to make one device as a server and other as a client

Comment: Yes one server and other all device client

Comment: Create  a server using socket that will accept the request fetch data from sqlite and send back response.

Comment: Please any reference link provide

Comment: Please refer https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/